# CodeCommit - Git push fatal: Tree exceeded the maximum allowed size

Tags: git, aws-codecommit

I made a local commit and all worked well
When I try to push to CodeCommit, I am receiving the following error:

pack-objects died of signal 13e Tree exceeded the maximum allowed size of 6291456 bytes

What is this error? I didn't find any explanation on web.

Thanks

André

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you ran into a repository limit on CodeCommit's side. Your repository seems to have a Tree Object (See: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects) that is larger than 6MB. This is pretty uncommon. Tree objects should only contain metadata about files (blobs) and directories (other trees) inside the corresponding directory. They rarely go larger than a few kilobytes in size.

CodeCommit limits documentation indirectly mentions this:

> "There is no limit on the number or the total size of all files in a single commit, as long as the metadata does not exceed 6 MB and a single blob does not exceed 2 GB."

In this case, the 'metadata' referred to here is actually the Tree object size.

Limits Documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/limits.html

Answer (score 0):

We had this similar issue, below are our findings.

This tells the remote git repository exceeds the size. If you are sending the files over http(s) you might need to switch to ssh. Since the limitation could be due to http payload size.

If you own the remote server it is worth checking the disk space to make sure it can receive the payload you are trying to push.

Hope it helps.